# Convert WIDE to LONG in R varying=Date

Tags: r

I have a .csv file I have imported to R, I need to convert the Data to Long format, where varying will be date from 4/1/1996 to 12/16/2017.
The data has been stored in R, where the variables are RegionName, State, the sizerank and the different Dates which the observation was made for each Region in each State. 
Of course, the Idvar, will be the SizeRank:

[image: Part of the Data is short as a snapshot]

Comment: have a look at the `tidyr` package and the function `gather` therein. This does what you want.

Comment: What about using the reshape(), function?

Comment: @akrun, don't really think that this is a duplicate of the one you've linked to as this is clearly R related and the other one is about bash.

Comment: @takje Reopened the post

Comment: @akrun, it is a duplicate question however. Posted the r-specific link in an earlier comment without mentioning you.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("file.csv")
melt(dt, id.vars = c("RegionName", "State", "SizeRank"), variable.name = "date")
```

I think this does what you want.